# Using array as a condition in where clause codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the problems using the array input as a value in `WHERE` clause.

But don't want to use more than once in WHERE clause code.

In my case, this is what I want :

```
$cond = array('job_id' => $job_id_var, 'job_name' => $job_name_var);
//WHERE clause
$this->where($cond); //only using once WHERE clause code like this, array as input
//which means
WHERE job_id = '$job_id_var' AND job_name = '$job_name_var'
```

is it possible to do that in codeigniter?

Comment: It is possible in codeIgniter. `$this->db->where($cond); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `->where()` method can support that.

Since you **do not want** to cascade it:

```
$this->db->where('job_id', $job_id_var);
$this->db->where('job_name', $job_name_var);
```

`->where()` can handle array input as well:

```
$cond = array('job_id'=>$job_id_var, 'job_name'=>$job_name_var);

$this->db->where($cond); // here, only used once.

$query = $this->db->get('hello_table');
$result = $query->result_array();

return $result;
```